# Binary Tree Traversal adding empty values to trees

Tags: python, tree, binary-tree, tree-traversal

I am trying to recursively traverse a binary tree in preorder, inorder, and postorder. I have to return a list of the specified traversal, the code for  preorder traversal is below:

```
class EmptyValue:
    pass


class BinaryTree:
    """Binary Tree class.

    Attributes:
    - root (object): the item stored at the root, or EmptyValue
    - left (BinaryTree): the left subtree of this binary tree
    - right (BinaryTree): the right subtree of this binary tree
    """

    def __init__(self, root=EmptyValue):
        """ (BinaryTree, object) -> NoneType

        Create a new binary tree with a given root value,
        and no left or right subtrees.
        """
        self.root = root    # root value
        if self.is_empty():
            # Set left and right to nothing,
            # because this is an empty binary tree.
            self.left = None
            self.right = None
        else:
            # Set left and right to be new empty trees.
            # Note that this is different than setting them to None!
            self.left = BinaryTree()
            self.right = BinaryTree()

    def is_empty(self):
        """ (BinaryTree) -> bool
        Return True if self is empty.
        Note that only empty binary trees can have left and right
        attributes set to None.
        """
        return self.root is EmptyValue

    def preorder(self):
        """ (BinaryTree) -> list
        Return a list of the items in this tree using a *preorder* traversal.
        """

        pre_order_list = []

        if self.root is None:
            pass


        if self.root != None:

            pre_order_list.append(self.root)


        if self.left and self.right:

            return pre_order_list + (self.left.preorder()) +  self.right.preorder()

        else:
            pass



        return pre_order_list
```

I enter the following commands into the command prompt,

```
tree1 = BinaryTree(1)
tree2 = BinaryTree(2)
tree3 = BinaryTree(3)
tree4 = BinaryTree(4)
tree5 = BinaryTree(5)
tree6 = BinaryTree(6)
tree1.left = tree2
tree1.right = tree3
tree2.left = tree4
tree2.right = tree5
tree3.left = tree6
tree1.preorder()
```

but since tree3.right is None and I get this error:

[`1, 2, 4, <class '__main__.EmptyValue'>, <class '__main__.EmptyValue'>, 5, <class '__main__.EmptyValue'>, <class '__main__.EmptyValue'>, 3, 6, <class '__main__.EmptyValue'>, <class '__main__.EmptyValue'>, <class '__main__.EmptyValue'>`]

I don't want the `"<class '__main__.EmptyValue'> "` to be in the list, I can't seem to figure out how to ignore items that are empty value or basically None.

Comment: One way could be to have two identically-named methods in both `EmptyValue` and `BinaryTree` that indicates whether current node is empty. You could be able to use that function call to determine whether to add to your traversals.

Comment: Why do you need `EmptyValue`?  BTW, it's good practice to let your class inherit from `object`, eg, `class BinaryTree(object):`. Also, don't use `!=` with `None`, use  `is not`, eg `if self.root is not None'. But really, you should modify your code so that you aren't essentially testing the same condition twice in a row.